# Laravel with App Engine Standard Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, php-7, laravel-6

This is driving me crazy second day. I'm new to Laravel and trying to get Laravel 6 work on Google App Engine Standard.
Tried: [This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard) and other ones, but it still fails to load Laravel index page

What I have done:

1. Created new Laravel project
2. Checked that Laravel is working on local host with `php artisan serve`
3. Generated new key with `php artisan key:generate --show`
4. Created app.yaml file with:

```
runtime: php72

env_variables:
  APP_KEY: iktbUa2quYPV2av3zDx0XAuEVjwzVQY/oMfyI2PQNKk=
  APP_STORAGE: /tmp
  VIEW_COMPILED_PATH: /tmp
  SESSION_DRIVER: cookie
```

4. Modified bootstrap/app.php by adding `$app->useStoragePath(env('APP_STORAGE', base_path() . '/storage'));`
5. Ran`composer remove --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server`
6. Also ran:
   `php artisan cache:clear`, 
   `php artisan route:cache`,
   `php artisan config:clear`,
   `php artisan view:clear` (as other tutorials suggested)
7. And `gcloud app deploy`

And I get error: "**Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found**"

[image]

Comment: Did you registered your provider inside `config/app.php [provider & alias]`  ?

Answer (score 52):

If you're facing this issue after upgrading composer 1.0 to 2.0. Then you can follow this step:

1. Go to the project directory
2. Run composer install
3. Run composer dump-autoload
4. Try to run `php artisan serve`
   It solved for me

Comment: I upgraded from composer 1.x to composer 2.x so this issue was reported. your answer helped me. Thanks :)

Comment: It even works without step 3. Thank you

Comment: I have updated the PHP version and then got this error but it's solve after `composer install`

Answer (score 11):

Please Try

```
composer dump-autoload
```

It solved for me

Comment: This broke my all application.

Comment: @KrishnaKarki This just ensures that your dependency files are properly getting discovered and loaded. It def shouldn't break your application, unless the dependencies themselves correctly break your application, or unless you have a discrepancy in your composer versions (i.e. installed the initial deps with composer v1, and installed new deps with v2, etc.)

Comment: This helped out! Thank you so much. Any idea what just happened to understand this more technically?

Answer (score 8):

App engine install dependency with "--no-dev" flag. If your application is debug mode and there is an error application is try to render error page by "facade/ignition" packages.

Solve-1: You can move "facade/ignition" dependency from "require-dev" to "dev" in composer.json file

Solve-2: You can run as production environment and with false APP_DEBUG flag

Answer (score 5):

I have experienced other errors as well, most of them gave me Error **500** and

`nginx: [warn] the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /tmp/google-config/nginx.conf:3` in Stackdriver Logger

Also I was not aware that App Engine was executing composer.json on build (see [Specifying Dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/specifying-dependencies)). And it seems the issue was that it cached that.

Everything **was resolved by replacing command in step 7.** :

`gcloud app deploy` with **`gcloud beta app deploy --no-cache`**

It seems that if I would have done all steps as in [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-laravel-on-appengine-standard) from the start I would not have any issues.

Answer (score 4):

I try
**composer update**
and its working fine

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
php artisan route:clear
```

and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

Try running

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project terminal and run :

1. `composer install`
2. `composer dump-autoload`
3. `php artisan serve`

And your problem will go away.

Answer (score 1):

I am also new to Laravel and I have experienced with this issue, and I searched solution which was

- first run this command on your terminal

`composer update`

- second run the command on below

`composer dump-autoload`

and then see the result :)

Comment: In my case, I need run `composer dump-autoload` to use my helpers. It works for me… and update my laravel project from v7.28 to v7.30 !

Answer (score 0):

just uncomment soduim line from your ini file

before

```
;extension=sodium
```

after

```
extension=sodium
```

Answer (score 0):

just remove cache contents in bootstrap folder and problem will be fixed!

Answer (score -1):

If you are facing this issue while running phpUnit tests then try to clear cache of bootstrap folder.