# Laravel Error - Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-7, google-cloud-console

In google cloud console, when I deploy project using command `php artisan config:cache`, it shows error :

> In Application.php line 690: Class 'Facade\Ignition\IgnitionServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Try

`php artisan route:clear` and you're good to go

Comment: It shows above error

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` and try

Answer (score 3):

`composer dump-autoload` didn't work for me. I deleted vendor folder and run `composer update` and I can run `php artisan` again

Answer (score 3):

I had to delete the **vendors** folder and then run

```
composer install
```

to make everything fall in place and to get rid of the error!

Answer (score 2):

You have to run the `composer dump-autoload` command which won't download anything new, but looks for all of the classes it needs to include again. It just regenerates the list of all classes that need to be included in the project.

Comment: This worked for me also but note though that someone said he applied the same `composer dump-autoload` solution but it broke his application instead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58087153/laravel-with-app-engine-standard-class-facade-ignition-ignitionserviceprovider

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the vendor folder and using the `composer update` command worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

first Check Server.php file is still in the root folder

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

$uri = urldecode(
    parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);

// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```

then run

```
composer update
```

and then project will start without any issue